# Clickable preview image that auto-loads a Youtube video

Tags: youtube, lazy-loading, youtube-javascript-api

We're working on implementing a clickable preview image that will play a Youtube video.

The goal is to avoid loading unnecessary JS code and improve Google Pagespeed score.

We have implemented a solution that works.

**But the problem is that it takes two clicks to actually load the Youtube video**: one click to display the Youtube video, another to actually start the video.

I know for a fact that it's possible to load start such videos in one click, because solutions such as [this one](https://www.kweber.com/lazy-load-videos/) exist (but it requires Wordpress)

How do we approach this? Is there a ready-made solution for implementing lazy loading for videos? (that doesn't require Wordpress?)

Answer (score 0):

I used this small tutorial: https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/

You show a thumbnail image of a YouTube video and '*When a visitor clicks the play button, the thumbnail image is replaced with the standard YouTube video player with autoplay set to 1 so it plays the video instantly.*'

You need javascript, css and html (no Wordpress). Hope it helps you.